# Schema to load JSON to Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have the following JSON, which is the result of parsing urls parameters from a log file.

```
{
    "title": "History of Alphabet",
    "author": [
        {
            "name": "Larry"
        },
    ]
}

{
    "title": "History of ABC",
}

{
    "number_pages": "321",
    "year": "1999",
}

{
    "title": "History of XYZ",
    "author": [
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "age": "63"
        },
        {
            "nickname": "Bill",
            "dob": "1955-03-29"
        }
    ]
}
```

All the fields in top-level, "title", "author", "number_pages", "year" are optional. And so are the fields in the second level, inside "author", for example.

How should I make a schema for this JSON when loading it to BQ?

A related question:
For example, suppose there is another similar table, but the data is from different date, so it's possible to have different schema. Is it possible to query across these 2 tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I make a schema for this JSON when loading it to BQ?

The following schema should work.  You may want to change some of the types (e.g. maybe you want the dob field to be a `TIMESTAMP` instead of a `STRING`), but the general structure should be similar.  Since types are `NULLABLE` by default, all of these fields should handle not being present for a given row.

```
[
    {
        "name": "title",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "name": "author",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "name": "age",
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "name": "nickname",
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "name": "dob",
                "type": "STRING"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "number_pages",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "name": "year",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    }
]
```

> A related question: For example, suppose there is another similar table, but the data is from different date, so it's possible to have different schema. Is it possible to query across these 2 tables?

It should be possible to union two tables with differing schemas without too much difficulty.

Here's a quick example of how it works over public data (kind of a silly example, since the tables contain zero fields in common, but shows the concept):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.natality), 
    (SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare) 
LIMIT 100;
```

Note that you need the `SELECT *` around each table or the query will complain about the differing schemas.